# How to define addition on the naturals as a function rather than with the successor "function".

Tags: group-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, monoid, natural-numbers

It is my understanding that when an algebraic structure (in this case a commutative monoid) is equipped with an operation (in this case $+$) that binary operation is a function of two variables.

I usually define a function $f$ as a set of $n$-tuples. For example:

$$\div\equiv\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}^3\mid x=y\times z \land y\not=0\}$$

Now we can call $\div(x,y)=z$. So, for example, $\div(15,3)=5$ or if we use more conventional notation: $15\div 3=5$.

My problem is that whenever I have seen references to the addition of natural numbers, it is in the context of the successor function $S(n)$. Thus addition is defined indirectly via two rules:

$$x+0=x$$
$$x+S(y)=S(x+y)$$

*Where $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers and $S(n)=n\cup\{n\}$.*

I don't have any problem with *how* these two rules uniquely define addition of the naturals. Rather, my problem is with how I can take this definition and put it in the form above, the one in which the $+$ operator is defined as a set of $3$-tuples rather than a shorthand for some logical formula.

Comment: Once this definition is done, you're allowed to write $\{(x, y, z) :x+y=z\} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of addition you cite is an *inductive* definition: given a relation $R\subseteq\mathbb{N}^3$, it returns a larger relation $R^+$ consisting of:

- all triples in $R$,
- all triples of the form $(x, 0, x)$, and
- all triples $(a,  b, c)$ such that for some $u, v$ we have $b=S(u)$, $S(v)=c$, and  $(a, u, v)\in R$.

For any relation $R$, let $LFP(R)$ be the *least fixed point* of $R$: namely, the intersection of all relations containing $R$ and left unchanged by $^+$. (Exercise: show that this exists.)

The ternary relation corresponding to addition is $LFP(\emptyset)$. Alternately, we can define it as $$\{(x, y, z): (x, y, z)\in LFP(\emptyset)\},$$ or $$\{(x, y, z): \forall R\subseteq\mathbb{N}^3(R^+=R\implies (x, y, z)\in R)\}.$$

Meanwhile, the fact that inductive definitions are not first-order provides an obstacle to any simpler definition; in particular, addition is not first-order definable in the structure $(\mathbb{N}, S)$ (and similarly multiplication isn't definable in the structure $(\mathbb{N}, +)$).

Comment: Is there a way to define addition of the naturals using set theory in a way that is consistent with other definitions of functions? I've heard that you could define addition in terms of cardinal numbers but then how do you relate that back tot he von Nuemann construction of the naturals?

Comment: @OzanerHansha I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. The definitions of ordinal and cardinal arithmetic are inductive definitions, very similar to that above; they then *restrict* to the von Neumann naturals. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "consistent with other definitions of functions."

Comment: By consistent I meant like how I defined division, as a set of ordered triplets in set builder notation. So then is it not possible to construct an addition operator on the naturals without induction? Is this problematic?

Comment: @OzanerHansha I did define addition as a set of ordered triples, that was the whole point of my answer! Why would using induction be problematic?

Comment: Well it requires second order logic right? That seems like a big step. Now everything based off of the addition of naturals (like multiplication, or the construction of the integers maybe) must take place in second order ZFC right?

Comment: @OzanerHansha No. It all depends on *what you take as primitive*. For example, your definition of division doesn't work without multiplication already being defined. At some point you have to postulate an **ambient structure or theory** containing some primitives - at which point you can talk about definability in that structure or across models of that theory. We do indeed have various negative results here, such as those in my comment above (addition not being definable in the naturals using successor alone and multiplication not being definable in the naturals with addition alone). (cont'd)

Comment: Note: there is an interplay here between the complexity of the *logic* we use to make our definitions and the complexity of the *background structure or theory* those definitions take place in. For instance, addition isn't definable over the naturals with successor **in first-order logic**, but my answer shows that it *is* definable over the naturals with successor in second-order logic. In general, model theory (for primarily first-order logic) or abstract model theory (for others) are relevant subjects if these sort of "complexity concerns" are interesting to you (they certainly are to me!).